# Could not install Node-Red nodes : rc=null

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I tried to install **node-red-contrib-cos** (for IBM Cloud Object Storage service) on IBM Cloud/Node-RED v1.0.1:

Log:

```
2019-10-28T15:29:51.265Z Install : node-red-contrib-cos 0.0.18

2019-10-28T15:30:03.407Z npm install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --save --save-prefix="~" --production node-red-contrib-cos@0.0.18
2019-10-28T15:30:13.380Z rc=null
```

It works okay on my Mac, same Node-RED version.

Comment: You most likely blew your apps memory budget. You can try again or edit the `package.json` and restage the app to have the node installed at startup

Comment: that was it, much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hashed out in the comments

Node-RED node installs via the **Manage palette** option can fail when running on IBM Cloud due to the memory constraints for the application.

You have 3 options:

1. Try again, it may just be that you were just over the limit and a dip in load on the app may be enough to allow the install to complete.
2. Increase the memory assigned to your application
3. User the continuous delivery feature to add the node you want to the app's `package.json` file as a dependency and restage the app. The restage process is not capped to the same memory limits.